# Permutation of Automobile License

Tags: permutations

How many different automobile license numbers can be formed by using $1$ to $6$ digits preceded by a letter if the digit immediately following the letter cannot be zero and the letters *O* and *I* are excluded?

My answer is
$24\cdot9\cdot10\cdot10\cdot10\cdot10\cdot10 = 21600000$

Is this correct?

Comment: This looks like it would be the right answer if every licence plate used exactly 6 digits. Do you need to consider licence plates that use fewer than 6 digits?

Comment: I think i will use 6 digits because it is stated in the problem. I'm also confused because automobile license consist of 3 letters and 3 digits. Since it is indicated in the problem i used 6 digits.

Comment: Well, I think you're correct if the question wants you to find the number of possibilities with exactly six digits. If plates are allowed any number of digits between 1 and 6 (inclusive), then you'd need to add together a number of similar terms. I don't think the question is meant to reflect what system is actually used for plates in the real world.

Comment: I agree. Since the problem stated that it is 6 digits. Then is should probably follow it.Do you think my answer is correct?

Comment: I think it is correct if the the plates must have exactly six digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $24.9$ one digit plates, $24.9.10$ two digit plates, ..., and $24.9.10^5$ 6 digit plates. Adding those numbers results in a total of $24.(10^6-1)$ plates. That is $23,999,976$ plates all together.

Comment: I thought it is asking for 6 digits only?

Comment: It said 1 to 6 digits which means 1 ,2,3,...,6 digits.